# which of the functions can be used only with numeric values

Tags: sql, function

Anybody tell me that Which of the following functions can be used only with numeric values.

```
A. Avg
B. minimum
C. Length
D. Round
E. Sum
```

Comment: And if we tell you you will give us grades? :-)

Comment: What happens when you test them all?

Comment: This can be answered without even testing it - just using common sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sql you can use AVG(), ROUND() and SUM() only with numeric values.